# Cannot serialize Android.net.Uri with Gson

Tags: android, gson

When I tried to serialize Android.net.Uri with Gson, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.net.Uri$Part declares multiple JSON fields named __robo_data__

at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:115)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:164)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
```

I tried using JsonSerializer, TypeAdapter like the following, but none of them work. Does anyone know the work around?

```
public void getUriJson() {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();

    builder.registerTypeAdapter(Uri.class, new UriSerializer());
    String json = builder.create().toJson(uri);
}

private class UriSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Uri> {

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Uri src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return new JsonPrimitive(src.toString());
    }
}
```

Note: I am not trying to get the string of Uri. I have a Uri field in my object, which has many fields. All of them can be serialized except for the uri.

Comment: How about writing a customer serializer for your object that serializes the `Uri` field as a string?

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman That works, but my object has many fields, so I am wondering instead of calling JsonSerializationContext.serialize(Object, Type)  to serialize each of them, and serialize the Uri field as a string, is there a easier way.